# Неправильно показываются добавленные на страницу посты

Tags: javascript, html, css

После нажатия на кнопку вызывается функция, которая делает запрос и добавляет посты со следующей страницы к уже существующим. Но добавляются они не так, как хотелось бы, проблема почти наверняка не в самом скрипте (пробовал несколько разных), все работало нормально, пока не был добавлен футер на сайт.

Теперь при прокручивании до кнопки и нажатии на неё посты добавляются на страницу, но показываются неправильно, но при след. нажатии новая пачка постов показывается правильно.

Как это можно починить?

---

На изображении:

1. Как выглядит кнопка и посты
2. Что должно происходить при нажатии
3. Что происходит сейчас при нажатии

Вьюпорт показан полупрозрачным зеленым цветом.

[image: Иллюстрация]

Пример скрипта, используемого для кнопки:

```
'use strict';

(function ($, undefined) {
  var load_posts_button = $('.js-load-posts');
  var pagination_next_url = $('link[rel=next]').attr('href');
  load_posts_button.click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var request_next_link = pagination_next_url.split(/page/)[0] + 'page/' + pagination_next_page + '/';

    $.ajax({
      url: request_next_link
    }).done(function (data) {
      var posts = $('.js-post', data);

      $('.js-post-feed').append(posts);

      pagination_next_page++;

      if (pagination_next_page > pagination_available_pages) {
        load_posts_button.attr('disabled', true);
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал накидать имитацию того что ты делаешь - ничего не прокручивается. Где-то у тебя в скрипте что-то мутное судя по всему.

```js
    $("#add").click(function(e){
       $('<div class="block"></div><div class="block"></div><div class="block"></div><div class="block"></div>').appendTo("#main");
    })
```

```css
        .block{
        display:inline-block;
        width: 45%;
        margin:2%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        height:300px;
        }
        
        footer{
        margin-top:50px;
        padding:40px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.4);
        text-align:center;
        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main">
       <div class="block"></div>
       <div class="block"></div>
       <div class="block"></div>
       <div class="block"></div>
    </div>

    <button id="add">Добавить</button>

    <footer>Все права защищены - 2018</footer>
```

Зеленая область = текущее положение пользователя на странице? И ошибка в том что при добавлении контента тебя прокручивает вниз страницы вместо того чтобы оставаться на месте? Если да то - футер безусловно мог повлиять на ситуацию, но решать проблему тебе все равно придется через скрипт - чтобы не прокручивало.

Comment: Да и да, когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку, он ожидает, что посты добавятся снизу и можно продолжать скроллить вниз и просматривать их. Сейчас же они добавляются в список постов, но вьюпорт остается внизу, где кнопка. То есть приходится проскроллить вверх, найти то место, где остановился, а потом скроллить вниз и просматривать посты. Каким образом решить эту проблему через скрипт? Нужно при нажатии на кнопку зафиксировать положение пользователя как-то?

Comment: обновил ответ, запусти, посмотри. нормальное поведение как ты и ожидаешь.

Comment: Проблема не со скриптом. Если никаких секцией под кнопкой нет (т.е. она находится в конце страницы), то все работает нормально.

Comment: @newcomer проблема скорее всего со скриптом, даже если она и возникает только при добавлении футера. Поправил пример в котором добавлен футер - все ок работает - значит правильный скрипт вполне будет удовлетворять твоим требованиям. я конечно допускаю что возможно у тебя там какие-то навороты с css, но тут увы - приводи тогда полный код со стилями и разметкой который запустить можно и отладит - попробую помочь.